# Change a string within a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to apply a function to a list of string within a list within a list, and then return it in the same form. For example, I have a large list with some strings within two sublists. I want to add the letter a to each string, and then get my list back in the same form.

```
some_large_list = [['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ['str4', 'str5', 'str6']]

new_large_list = []

for lst in some_large_list:
    for word in lst:
        new_large_list.append(add_letter_a(word))

new_large_list = [['str1a', 'str2a', 'str3a'], ['str4a', 'str5a', 'str6a']]
```

but instead I get:

```
new_large_list = ['str1a', 'str2a', 'str3a', 'str4a', 'str5a', 'str6a']
```

How do I keep the strings in their separate sublists?

Answer (score 0):

You are going through list of lists, you should re-construct it the same way. In addition to that, you should implement your function `add_letter_a`. 
Try to use a list s. to store items that u re-create, and another main list to store the lists.
Your code should look like:

```
some_large_list = [['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ['str4', 'str5', 'str6']]

new_large_list = []

def add_letter_a(word):
    return word+'a'

for lst in some_large_list:
    s=[]
    for word in lst:
        s.append(add_letter_a(word))
    new_large_list.append(s)

print new_large_list
```

Output:

```
[['str1a', 'str2a', 'str3a'], ['str4a', 'str5a', 'str6a']]
```

There is better way to do it using `list comprehension.`

```
some_large_list = [['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ['str4', 'str5', 'str6']]
new_large_list = [[ word+'a' for word in listOfWords ] for listOfWords in some_large_list ]
print new_large_list
```